# VS: XAML-Designer Error (ArgumentException - Same Key has already been added)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, exception, designer

I was training myself to learn C# with console application projects and everything was fine. And I thought it was time for me to step it up and try learning WPF Applications. However whenever I try to open or create a WPF-Application I always get the this error below.

I tried finding fix and tried reinstall but itdoes not work. I tried also many other Solutions from the web.

So I am able to create any projects but not WPF Applications, because the XAML-Designer not load.

I don't know how to fix this issue. Please help me if you're able to..

**Exception:**
An Unhandled Exception has occured.

System.ArgumentException

An item with the same key has already been added.

at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource) at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Utility.Telemetry.VsTelemetryService.RegisterDesignerProcessSession(Int32 pid) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Utility.Feedback.WatsonTracker.RegisterSession(Int32 processID) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Utility.DesignerSessionTracker.RecordDesignerStart(Int32 processID, String isolationTargetIdentifier, Boolean mockCustomTypes, String buildConfiguration) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo, IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, String baseDirectory) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, IObjectCatalog catalog) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry, IServiceProvider serviceOverrides) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.b__0() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

[image: The Exception as Image]

Answer (score 4):

Please have a look at this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42128029/6913689) from a similar question with almost identical stack trace.

FIX: Delete or rename file "C:\Program" then click on "Click here to reload the designer" in Visual Studio.

Comment: Are you kidding me?! I've been struggling with this problem for over a year and this finally worked!